# How to fix 'Unable to install packages' error while trying to run R script through command line?

Tags: r, batch-file, command

I am trying to run an R script through the command line. My R script contains statement for inclusion of library and some methods of the same library as given here. The command line statement I am using to run the code is as below.

Test.R

```
library("readxl")
sales <- read_xlsx("<file path>", sheet = 1)
```

Commands:

```
cd "C:\Users\Debasish.sena\Desktop\out"
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" -e "install.packages('readxl', repos = 'https://cran.us.r-project.org')"
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\Debasish.sena\Documents\Test.R" "C:\Users\Debasish.sena\Desktop\out\Test.Rout"
```

While executing the command I am getting the error as below:
Warning in `install.packages("readxl", repos = "https://cran.us.r-project.org")` :
  'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library"' is not writable
Error in `install.packages("readxl", repos = "https://cran.us.r-project.org")` :
  unable to install packages
Execution halted

I am expecting the R script to be executed and the results stored in 'sales' variable

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not logged in as Administrator, or you are trying to install on a remote system.  Can you print the result of `.libPaths()`?

Comment: The results of .libPaths() is "C:/Users/Debasish.sena/Documents/R/R-3.3.2/library"

Comment: Yeah. As you can see the directory is different from R's default library directory: "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library". If you are not running R on a remote computer, you must log out and log in as Administrator. It might work to just right-click on your IDE and choose "Run as Administrator" if you have the credentials.

Comment: I tried running the batch file as Administrator and some of the packages got loaded and some not.

Comment: Is `.libPaths()` different when you run it as Admin.?

Comment: No. .libPaths() is the same.

Comment: What's the message when you try to load a package that cannot be loaded as admin?

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar issue, I solved it as follows:

1. I created an Environment variable called **R_LIBS** for my account (NOT System variable) as **R_LIBS=C:\Users\W.Aftab\Documents\R\win-library\4.0**
2. Then I restarted the VS code as I was using its terminal to call Rscript.exe. you can restart the command prompt if you are using it to call Rscript.

That's it,

I tested it on 64-bit windows 10 enterprise.